# What does a colon at the beginning of HTML attribute names in a Vue template mean?

Tags: html, vue.js, syntax

```
<circle
   r="3"
   :cx="airport.x"
   :cy="airport.y"
   class="airport__marker"
/>
```

Is this the same as `v-bind:cx` and `v-bind:cy` ?

Comment: No idea, it's not valid unless there's somehing you are using that would preprocess this.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it comes from a Vue app.  Specifically a Vue template.

`:cx="airport.x"` is a shortcut form of `v-bind:cx="airport.x"`

Which is saying get the value of attribute `cx` from the variable `airport.x` in the code.
So if `airport.x = 100` then the generated SVG would have `cx="100"`.

You can read more about this here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands

Comment: Thanks Paul ! . . . very well explained